@symfony/webpack-encore migration to vite-plugin-symfony
I'm trying to migrate from @symfony/webpack-encore migration to vite-plugin-symfony and got an issue.
When webpack-encore dev server starts, it generates chunks under Encore.setOutputPath('web/assets/') directory, which is not the case for vite-plugin-symfony. It just generates web/assets/.vite/entrypoints.json. Here is an example:
"entryPoints": {
    "app": {
      "js": [
        "http://localhost:8080/web/vwm/js/app.js"
      ]
    },
    "chosen": {
      "js": [
        "http://localhost:8080/web/vwm/js/chosen.js"
      ]
    },
    "jquery": {
      "js": [
        "http://localhost:8080/web/vwm/js/jquery-webpack.js"
      ]
    },
    "users-legacy": {
      "js": [
        "http://localhost:8080/web/src/modules/classes/Apps/User/Resources/assets/js/users.js"
      ]
    },
    ...
}

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    symfonyPlugin(),
    vue({
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          includeAbsolute: false,
          base: null,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 8000
  },
  preview: {
    host: true,
    port: 8000
  },
  root: './',
  base: '/assets',
  publicDir: false,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue', '.ts'],
    alias: {
      root: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
      ...
    },
  },
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: false,
    sourcemap: process.env.MODE !== 'production',
    manifest: true,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
    outDir: 'web/',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        'users-legacy': path.resolve(__dirname,'./src/modules/classes/VWM/Apps/Resources/assets/js/users.js'),
      },
    },
  },
  appType: 'mpa'
});

Basically I'm trying to achieve 'webpack-like' behaviour for vite, where files for dev server is served into a web/assets folder. I tried to use vite build --watch command, but it takes 30 second for both starting a server and reloading it after changes.
